# Troubles with \centerline for center a line of text in a two column document

Tags: macros, horizontal-alignment, two-column

I'm composing a two column document with the `scrartcl`class. I need to emphasize few sentences along the text with an special typographic highlight. I was trying with the `\centerline`command but it centres my text between both columns or something else.

In fact I want to create a new command for that in this way: `\newcommand{\resalte}[1]{\textbf{\textsf{\large #1}}}` I want to add in the definition the `\centerline` for

An MWE could be:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,DIV=13,titlepage=false,twocolumn=on]{scrartcl}
%\usepackage[DIV=14]{typearea}
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[english=british,french=quotes,german=quotes,spanish=mexican]{csquotes}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    bookmarks=true,         % show bookmarks bar?
    unicode=true,           % non-Latin characters in Acrobat’s bookmarks
    pdftoolbar=true,        % show Acrobat’s toolbar?
    pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat’s menu?
    pdffitwindow=false,     % window fit to page when opened
    %pdfstartview={FitH},   % fits the width of the page to the window
    pdftitle={Document title},    % title
    pdfauthor={Lev Bronstein},     % author
    pdfsubject={Study},   % subject of the document
    pdfcreator={Listopad},   % creator of the document
    pdfproducer={Me}, % producer of the document
    %pdfkeywords={keyword1} {key2} {key3}, % list of keywords
    pdfnewwindow=true,      % links in new window
    colorlinks=true,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=teal,          % color of internal links (change box color with linkbordercolor)
    citecolor=green,        % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=red,      % color of file links
    urlcolor=blue,           % color of external links
    anchorcolor=magenta, % color for anchor texto
    filecolor=cyan, % color for urls which open local files
    menucolor=orange, % color for acrobat menu items
    runcolor=violet, % color for run links (launch annotations)
}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont{Warnock Pro} 
\setsansfont{Myriad Pro} 
\setmonofont{Consolas}

%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} 
\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,x11names,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\sisetup{
%output-decimal-marker = {,},
detect-weight= true, 
range-units = brackets,
list-final-separator = { \translate{and} },
list-pair-separator = { \translate{and} },
range-phrase = { \translate{to (numerical range)} },
}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[grid=true,gridcolor=cyan,subgridcolor=orange,gridunit=pt]{eso-pic}% dibuja la reticula de las paginas

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ohead{\textbf{Encabezado}
\ihead{\texttt{http://aradenatoria.net}}

\usepackage[stable,bottom]{footmisc}
\raggedbottom
\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000
%\setlength{\parskip}{3pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{30pt}

\parskip0.4\baselineskip

\newcommand{\resalte}[1]{\textbf{\textsf{\large #1}}}

\begin{document}

\titlehead{GAR}
\subject{Documento}
\title{Programa}
\subtitle{1938}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}
\publishers{Listopad}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents 

\section{The first section}

\noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eu ante egestas, eleifend urna non, volutpat tellus. Quisque ut sodales ligula. Phasellus dapibus dapibus ipsum sed vehicula. In imperdiet urna magna, id tincidunt purus dignissim quis. Aliquam non ligula auctor, auctor nisl in, hendrerit nulla. Aenean blandit ligula in sapien luctus, ut bibendum lectus pellentesque. Maecenas sit amet dui ipsum. Mauris metus ipsum, porta ac purus non, euismod venenatis lacus. Mauris rhoncus tortor nisl, a tincidunt justo ullamcorper sed. Donec tellus quam, aliquam ac ligula ac, tempus lacinia ligula. Phasellus vel lorem nisl. Aenean nunc tortor, blandit eget magna ut, eleifend facilisis risus. Morbi sed nulla nec nulla convallis vulputate eget id mauris. Ut laoreet laoreet odio eu convallis. 

 \resalte{Sed in tellus sollicitudin, imperdiet velit suscipit, sodales tortor.}

Donec id libero in sem vehicula elementum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vivamus molestie ultricies tortor, vitae tempor massa placerat et. Cras varius dictum dui sit amet vehicula. Ut venenatis mauris sit amet purus lobortis, vel mollis dui convallis. Phasellus euismod eu urna laoreet pulvinar. Ut neque nunc, vulputate in tincidunt id, convallis sed turpis. Etiam sagittis volutpat felis molestie venenatis. In non ultrices tellus. Vestibulum ultrices dolor eu sapien fermentum, id ultricies erat gravida. Proin nec tempor augue, vitae cursus ipsum. Nunc non nibh sit amet nisl pretium ullamcorper condimentum sit amet lorem. Integer vitae iaculis nibh, in fringilla lorem. Nam malesuada nunc elit, id convallis justo luctus vitae. Aenean sed ullamcorper turpis. Cras est nisl, dictum id felis non, lobortis aliquam diam.

Nullam accumsan odio nibh, sed blandit orci auctor id. Morbi a eros a velit pharetra tincidunt. Praesent consequat sem quis ipsum commodo, et placerat mi vulputate. Duis sed commodo augue. In aliquam placerat nunc non imperdiet. Donec id elit non ligula mattis consectetur nec in lectus. Donec turpis erat, tincidunt at posuere vel, posuere nec odio. Integer ipsum sapien, fermentum in eleifend at, vestibulum dictum turpis. Duis scelerisque aliquam sagittis. Quisque volutpat et nisl sed auctor.

Aliquam elit felis, condimentum vitae nulla ut, egestas egestas risus. Cras lacinia neque fermentum orci sollicitudin faucibus. Morbi non nunc porta, ornare libero quis, suscipit orci. Nunc adipiscing sem tellus, id adipiscing tellus blandit in. Vivamus mattis nulla mi, at malesuada orci ullamcorper id. Aenean volutpat suscipit elementum. Nunc orci mauris, consequat in commodo id, posuere id justo. In lacus sapien, volutpat sit amet nulla ac, vulputate sollicitudin dolor. Pellentesque iaculis nisi sit amet libero tristique adipiscing. Aliquam erat volutpat.

Aenean eu consequat tellus, quis posuere nunc. Duis tempus tristique lorem. Duis non tincidunt neque. Donec ac iaculis sem. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Integer ac quam lobortis, gravida eros vitae, convallis leo. Ut vel nisi eu nisl luctus bibendum. Nulla molestie tincidunt fringilla. Morbi sapien nulla, tincidunt id lorem a, luctus imperdiet erat.

Ut vestibulum consectetur ultrices. In ut mauris arcu. Donec posuere sollicitudin nibh quis lacinia. Nam nunc dui, congue sed ligula vitae, mollis mollis magna. Suspendisse potenti. Fusce nec libero at enim gravida accumsan id sed nibh. Quisque sed tincidunt magna, hendrerit tempus nunc. Nunc non sodales sem, at tincidunt massa. Etiam non varius lectus. Morbi at mi libero.

\section{Another section}

\noindent Curabitur ut neque non enim pulvinar facilisis. Aenean eget adipiscing sapien, eu sagittis urna. Suspendisse potenti. Nam sollicitudin posuere commodo. Phasellus risus dolor, laoreet tincidunt justo cursus, ornare scelerisque augue. Proin egestas quam vel neque ullamcorper mollis. Morbi augue neque, laoreet scelerisque nisl eu, venenatis porttitor dolor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec vel porttitor nisl, et fringilla massa. Suspendisse egestas, risus id eleifend condimentum, justo dui congue eros, id iaculis nibh nunc vel lorem. Sed sed nibh sed tellus laoreet porttitor ut nec justo. Aliquam egestas gravida imperdiet. Sed id mauris pulvinar, congue nunc a, pretium augue. Praesent eros dui, convallis sed arcu id, ultricies imperdiet lacus. Aliquam adipiscing urna quis ante commodo, eu gravida ligula volutpat. Aenean id nisi sit amet dolor porta volutpat.

Nam volutpat mauris ac eros hendrerit accumsan et id nulla. Nam ullamcorper nibh et est suscipit condimentum. Donec eu pellentesque arcu, quis pulvinar elit. Praesent neque libero, ullamcorper ut lacinia eu, ultricies nec ante. Nunc pharetra viverra tellus in suscipit. Maecenas orci ante, mattis sit amet tincidunt sit amet, rhoncus at felis. Cras ut massa quis tortor pellentesque commodo nec non magna. Nam blandit sapien quis enim iaculis faucibus. Aliquam at tincidunt augue.

Aliquam vestibulum sodales tristique. Integer sit amet orci diam. Mauris vitae ultrices nisi. Fusce placerat, ante sed fringilla vulputate, felis mi ullamcorper eros, at vehicula arcu nulla eget quam. Sed pulvinar lacus cursus ligula scelerisque lacinia. Donec quis lorem feugiat, eleifend massa a, auctor libero. Etiam ac augue egestas, mollis odio eget, dictum nisl. Mauris consequat euismod est, a ultricies nisl gravida a. Nunc rutrum id dui eu euismod. Aenean lobortis pellentesque risus, eget semper orci semper a. In massa massa, tincidunt molestie blandit a, fermentum auctor nisl. Donec placerat dignissim lorem ac vulputate. Pellentesque sed velit volutpat, adipiscing nisi sit amet, sollicitudin dui. In elementum id ligula sit amet varius. Donec nec elit tristique justo pharetra malesuada. Cras non egestas diam.

Nulla ante augue, mollis quis nisl nec, adipiscing ultricies massa. Donec dapibus erat vestibulum, lobortis est et, faucibus leo. Quisque justo dolor, scelerisque sed faucibus et, rhoncus ac augue. Nulla lobortis, mauris quis congue bibendum, libero orci bibendum urna, vel bibendum risus diam sit amet eros. Cras dictum ipsum placerat nunc dictum elementum. Nullam quis ultrices eros, a rutrum augue. Integer venenatis massa vel tellus pellentesque porta ut id odio. Curabitur ipsum odio, commodo vel nisi sed, pulvinar euismod velit. Cras rhoncus, turpis eu tristique aliquet, est nisi auctor dolor, vitae ornare risus libero nec sapien. Donec placerat et tellus in rhoncus. Sed gravida tempus tempus. Praesent a dictum risus. Nunc eget sem vitae libero vulputate dictum lacinia ac felis. Morbi sagittis enim a feugiat luctus. Curabitur aliquam justo turpis, vel malesuada tellus lacinia vel.

\end{document}
```

I can use the `center`environment, but I try to automatize the task instead to create a `center` environment manually eighty times. I've tried with `\centering`and `\centerline` but with not good results. Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: Please try to eliminate things that are _not_ related to the question. For instance, is `hyperseup` really required for this specific question? Or `\sisetup`? Same goes for packages.

Comment: \centerline is plain TeX, although I don't see why it should be affected by two-column (other than it wasn't designed to handle it).  Have you tried \makebox[\linewidth][c]{text}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following (re)definition of `\resalte` may do what you need:

```
\newcommand{\resalte}[1]{%
    \begin{quotation}%
    \centering\large\bfseries\sffamily #1%
    \end{quotation}}
```

The embedded `quotation` environment serves to provide some vertical separation from the preceding and subsequent material, as well as a left-hand and right-hand offset; this should make clear that the material isn't some unnumbered sectioning header. By using `\bfseries` and `\sffamily` instead of `\textbf` and `\textsf`, the macro lets its argument consist of two or more paragraphs. (You probably don't need this generality, but since there's no cost to providing it, one might as well provide it...)

The `\centering` command inhibits hyphenation of the material that's within its scope. If you do want to permit hyphenation, you should load the `ragged2e` package and use its `\Centering` macro instead of `\centering`:

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcommand{\resalte}[1]{%
    \begin{quotation}%
    \Centering\large\bfseries\sffamily #1%
    \end{quotation}}
```

Here's the look of the resulting text block of the first page of a moderately simplified form of your MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,DIV=13,titlepage=false,twocolumn=on]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[english=british,french=quotes,german=quotes,spanish=mexican]{csquotes}

\usepackage{fontspec} 
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro} % I don't have "Warnock Pro"
\setsansfont{Myriad Pro} 
\setmonofont{Consolas}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,x11names,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ohead{\textbf{Encabezado}}
\ihead{\texttt{http://aradenatoria.net}}

\usepackage[stable,bottom]{footmisc}
\raggedbottom
\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000

\setlength{\columnsep}{30pt}

\setlength{\parskip}{0.4\baselineskip}

\usepackage{ragged2e}       %% new
\newcommand{\resalte}[1]{%  %% modified
   \begin{quotation}%
   \Centering\bfseries\large\sffamily{#1}%
   \end{quotation}}

\begin{document}

\titlehead{GAR}
\subject{Documento}
\title{Programa}
\subtitle{1938}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}
\publishers{Listopad}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents 

\section{The first section}

\noindent
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eu ante egestas, eleifend urna non, volutpat tellus. Quisque ut sodales ligula. Phasellus dapibus dapibus ipsum sed vehicula. In imperdiet urna magna, id tincidunt purus dignissim quis. Aliquam non ligula auctor, auctor nisl in, hendrerit nulla. Aenean blandit ligula in sapien luctus, ut bibendum lectus pellentesque. Maecenas sit amet dui ipsum. Mauris metus ipsum, porta ac purus non, euismod venenatis lacus. Mauris rhoncus tortor nisl, a tincidunt justo ullamcorper sed. Donec tellus quam, aliquam ac ligula ac, tempus lacinia ligula. Phasellus vel lorem nisl. Aenean nunc tortor, blandit eget magna ut, eleifend facilisis risus. Morbi sed nulla nec nulla convallis vulputate eget id mauris. Ut laoreet laoreet odio eu convallis. 

\resalte{Sed in tellus sollicitudin, imperdiet velit suscipit, sodales tortor.}

Donec id libero in sem vehicula elementum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vivamus molestie ultricies tortor, vitae tempor massa placerat et. Cras varius dictum dui sit amet vehicula. Ut venenatis mauris sit amet purus lobortis, vel mollis dui convallis. Phasellus euismod eu urna laoreet pulvinar. Ut neque nunc, vulputate in tincidunt id, convallis sed turpis. Etiam sagittis volutpat felis molestie venenatis. In non ultrices tellus. Vestibulum ultrices dolor eu sapien fermentum, id ultricies erat gravida. Proin nec tempor augue, vitae cursus ipsum. Nunc non nibh sit amet nisl pretium ullamcorper condimentum sit amet lorem. Integer vitae iaculis nibh, in fringilla lorem. Nam malesuada nunc elit, id convallis justo luctus vitae. Aenean sed ullamcorper turpis. Cras est nisl, dictum id felis non, lobortis aliquam diam.

\resalte{Sed in tellus sollicitudin, imperdiet velit suscipit, sodales tortor.}

Nullam accumsan odio nibh, sed blandit orci auctor id. Morbi a eros a velit pharetra tincidunt. Praesent consequat sem quis ipsum commodo, et placerat mi vulputate. Duis sed commodo augue. In aliquam placerat nunc non imperdiet. Donec id elit non ligula mattis consectetur nec in lectus. Donec turpis erat, tincidunt at posuere vel, posuere nec odio. Integer ipsum sapien, fermentum in eleifend at, vestibulum dictum turpis. Duis scelerisque aliquam sagittis. Quisque volutpat et nisl sed auctor.

\resalte{Sed in tellus sollicitudin, imperdiet velit suscipit, sodales tortor.}

Aliquam elit felis, condimentum vitae nulla ut, egestas egestas risus. Cras lacinia neque fermentum orci sollicitudin faucibus. Morbi non nunc porta, ornare libero quis, suscipit orci. Nunc adipiscing sem tellus, id adipiscing tellus blandit in. Vivamus mattis nulla mi, at malesuada orci ullamcorper id. Aenean volutpat suscipit elementum. Nunc orci mauris, consequat in commodo id, posuere id justo. In lacus sapien, volutpat sit amet nulla ac, vulputate sollicitudin dolor. Pellentesque iaculis nisi sit amet libero tristique adipiscing. Aliquam erat volutpat.

\section{Another section}

\end{document}
```